# How do I retrieve the workerSize via Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan

Tags: powershell, azure

When creating a new AppServicePlan via the Azure PowerShell cmdlet `New-AzureRmAppServicePlan`, it is expected for me to add a `WorkerSize` such as Small, Medium or Large. For example:

```
$appServicePlanSettings = @{
    Name = "testingServicePlan";
    Location = "westeurope";
    Tier = "Basic";        
    ResourceGroupName = "testingResourceGroup";
    NumberofWorkers = 1;
    WorkerSize = "Medium";
}

New-AzureRmAppServicePlan @appServicePlanSettings
```

However, when I retrieve this same AppServicePlan via `Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan`, I am unable to find this information. Instead I come across the `Sku` property, which contains a `Size` property with for example the value B2, indicating the WorkerSize was medium. Example:

```
> $plan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "testingServicePlan" -ResourceGroupName "testingResourceGroup"
> $plan.Sku
Name     : B2
Tier     : Basic
Size     : B2
Family   : B
Capacity : 1
```

Am I supposed to keep track of these conversions in for example a HashList if I want to be able to compare the equivalent values, or is there some other way for me to retrieve the 'Medium'? I might have missed something but couldn't find this information.

According to PowerShell's `GetType()` method, the object returned is a `ServerFarmWithRichSku`, with as base type `Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.Resource`, but the documentation for this object was a bit lacking for me to get any further

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.resource?view=azuremgmtwebsites-1.6.0-preview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I test in my lab, `$plan.Sku.size` is `WorkerSize` value. The following is the result.

```
SMALL
Name     : B1
Tier     : Basic
Size     : B1
Family   : B
Capacity : 1

Medium
Name     : B2
Tier     : Basic
Size     : B2
Family   : B
Capacity : 1

Large
Name     : B3
Tier     : Basic
Size     : B3
Family   : B
Capacity : 1
```

I agree with Sridharan, but you had better use script like below:

```
$hash = @{}
$hash['B1'] = "Small"
$hash['B2'] = "Medium"
$hash['B3'] = "Large"
$hash['B4'] = "Extra Large"

$plan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "testingServicePlan" -ResourceGroupName "testingResourceGroup"
$val=$plan.Sku.Size
echo $hash[$val]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using a hash map like you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use Hash map for this.

But you can use "Family" from "Sku" to come over all B1,B2,M1,M2etc.,

```
>$hash = @{}
>$hash['S'] = "Small"
>$hash['M'] = "Medium"
>$hash['L'] = "Large"
>$hash['EL'] = "Extra Large"

>$plan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "testingServicePlan" -ResourceGroupName "testingResourceGroup"
> $val=$plan.Sku.Fmaily
>echo $hash[$val]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for necroposting, but I wish to propose my own way, which will fit all sizes (from Free till Premium).

```
$webAppHashSizes = @{}
$webAppHashSizes['1'] = "Small"
$webAppHashSizes['2'] = "Medium"
$webAppHashSizes['3'] = "Large"
$webAppHashSizes['4'] = "Extra Large"
$plan = Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -Name "testingServicePlan" -ResourceGroupName "testingResourceGroup"
echo $webAppHash[$plan.Sku.size.Substring(1,1)]
```