# Export the Type from an Azure Resource Group using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to export the Type field from Azure using PowerShell.

Using`Find-AzureRMResource` I get a lot of info, but I would like to have the type description as seen in the portal when viewing resources in a resource group:

[image]

Is it possible to get this info from Azure using PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TYPE` on Azure Portal equals `ResourceType` on PowerShell cmdlet. For example, `Network security group`  equals `Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups`. If you want to get it as `TYPE` on Portal, you could use hash map. For example.

```
$hash = @{}
$hash['Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups'] = "Network security group"
$result=Find-AzureRMResource -ResourceType "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups"
$test=$result.ResourceType[0]
echo $hash[$test]
```

[image]

Please refer to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926386/how-do-i-retrieve-the-workersize-via-get-azurermappserviceplan/44941570#44941570).

Thanks for RalJans share. Use a name convention with an abbrivation of the Type so I build a switch to get the correct name. Please refer to this [link](https://pastebin.com/hzDweTxj).

Comment: Thanks. We use a name convention with an abbrivation of the Type so I build a switch to get the correct name.

Unfortunately this requires an update everytime a new resource is selected.

Comment: I have posted the complete script here, it also contains logic to remove duplicates:

https://pastebin.com/hzDweTxj

Comment: Done

For clarification, our name convention for resource is like:
MSC-WEB for website
MSC-ASE for Application Service Environment
MSC-VNW for Virtual Network
Etc.

So the script reads those characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this information is exposed anywhere, but you can create a hash table to map those values and format output with that.